# Does bigquery api support CTE via python?

Tags: google-bigquery

I keep trying to run a query from python against bq, but it returns to me with;
`400 Syntax error: Unexpected end of statement at [1:3585]`

The bad thing about it, it's giving me a line number that I can't really track down.

This is the only query I have where I'm inserting to a table using a CTE.

`` Insert `x.y.z` (Date, Dollars)
WITH data AS (Select Date, Dollars FROM `x.y.temp`
SELECT Date, Dollars from data ``

The query works fine in BQ UI, but just encountering this problem from the api.

Comment: Are you sure that you're running the query that you think you are? Check your query history in the BigQuery web UI.

Comment: Yeah, the same query exists in the history and is green.
Just tried without inserting the data using the api, and it failed as well.

Comment: Is it possible that the `UseLegacySql` option is set? CTEs were not supported in the Legacy SQL dialect. Also, the number it's giving you isn't just a line number—it's a position, so `1:3585` means line 1, character 3585 . . . that may help you look for where it's choking (most text editors can show you the position or let you jump there with a "go to" command).

Comment: I tried #standardSQL, and without. Will check that character number. Is there something like traceback that would work for cloud functions?

Comment: @itsPav I'd also echo what Elliott said—but don't just check your user's history (since you probably ran in through the UI).  When you're on the history page, you can click the "Project history" tab to see users from all jobs, one of which should be from the user permissioned for your Python client.

Comment: Will check job history.

Comment: @itsPav In addition to the `#StandardSQL` query prefix, there's also a job option which I believe in the Python client is `job_config.use_legacy_sql = True`. If these two disagree, weird things can happen. Some of the client libraries also strip out the query prefix. Under the history, you can also check whether it ran as legacy SQL—just look for the "Use legacy SQL" value (usually at the end of the query details when you expand it)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196058/discussion-between-justbeez-and-itspav).

Comment: Can you post your Python code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CTEs are definitely supported when sending queries from the Python client library, but it's possible that there's some formatting issue from one of the helpers or custom code being used.

Boiling down our messages about formatting, here's a more comprehensive troubleshooting guide for everyone else's benefit:

1. Check that the `UseLegacySql` flag on the query isn't set, as WITH/Common Table Expressions (CTEs) aren't supported in that dialect. Also, even if you use the `#StandardSQL` query prefix, the other setting may override this (behavior when the two mismatch gets weird but doesn't always throw an error).
2. The error position being returned isn't just a line number, but rather line:position. So `1:3585` means line 1, character/position 3,585. Keep in mind, that's the position in the query that the library is generating—but may help you track down the issue.
3. Look at the query actually being generated. If you have access at a project level, you can do this in the UI under Query History, then selecting the "Project history" tab at the top of this page. (If you have a lot going on, you may need to filter by user or query text.) Note that you can also see if this was run as Legacy SQL from the query details. Be careful to also avoid your test you ran from the Console UI which will also show up there, but will show as your user (whereas your script will likely show as a service account or other authenticated user)
4. If you don't have access to the project queries to see the error and generated SQL, you can get the query text by retrieving the `.query` property after the query is sent. Based on the `google-cloud-python` documentation, this would look something like `query_job.query`. From there, pasting into a text editor you should be able to see the position where the error is being generated. The fact that the error is occurring on line 1 over 3K into the query may indicate that something isn't formatting correctly.

Best of luck in tracking it down!